# db files utility in IOS + phone-gap app development

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, cordova

I'm developing an IOS app with the `phonegap-framework`

Since `phone-gap` by default looks into `../Library/Caches/file__0/0000000000000001.db` and `../Library/Caches/Databases.db` for a database, so i copied these files which contain the db information into the mentioned locations once the app launches.

I know `0000000000000001.db` contains table creation statements, but was not sure as to what Databases.db contains because when tried with only `0000000000000001.db`, it doesn't work so both the files are required. So my main query is what does `Databases.db` contain? Also, Can i change the names of `0000000000000001.db` and `Databases.db`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database file names can not be changed. You can give your preferred name while opening database like this:

```
var db = window.openDatabase("PREFERRED DB NAME", "1.0", "DISPLAY DB NAME", 1000000);
```

Databases.db contains a table named **"Databases"** which contains name and path for your current database. It has mainly four columns: `name,displayName, estimatedSize,path`.
path field having entry `0000000000000001.db` for your database.
Comparing Databases column to `openDatabase` syntax:

```
name : PREFERRED DB NAME,
displayName : DISPLAY DB NAME,
estimatedSize : 1000000
```